# Errors when including a Tikz figure in a beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors, tikz-external

I want to include an external tikz file in a beamer presentation. I get following error: `Missing number, treated as zero`.

MWE:

content of .tex file:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pst]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}
\input{0pics/example.tikz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Content of `example.tikz`:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
%added
    axis equal image,
width=0.432\figurewidth,
height=0.576\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=15,
xlabel={$i$},
ymin=-3,
ymax=0,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.289,0.335)},anchor=south west,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot[const plot,color=black,solid,mark=*,mark options={solid}] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   -3\\
1   -1.89528461000566\\
2   -1.2165417194998\\
3   -0.782365188677032\\
};
\addlegendentry{$x^{(1)}(i)$};

\addplot[const plot,color=black,dashed,mark=*,mark options={solid}] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   -2.9\\
1   -1.89305581954404\\
2   -1.25193496088527\\
3   -0.834104149748474\\
};
\addlegendentry{$x^{(2)}(i)$};

\addplot[const plot,color=black,dashed,forget plot] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   0\\
15  0\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.432\figurewidth,
height=0.576\figureheight,
at={(0.568\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=15,
xlabel={$i$},
ymin=-0.8,
ymax=0.2,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot[const plot,color=black,dashed,mark=*,mark options={solid}] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   -0.0942343027470984\\
1   -0.0710987760069185\\
2   -0.0721957724782892\\
3   -0.0336261350013048\\
};
\addlegendentry{$u(i)$};

\addplot[const plot,color=black,solid,mark=*,mark options={solid}] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   -0.678266260177511\\
1   -0.451145429034797\\
2   -0.322832466389642\\
3   -0.200078970945606\\

};
\addlegendentry{$v(i)$};

\addplot[const plot,color=black,dashed,forget plot] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   0\\
14  0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Are you missing `pgfplots`?

Comment: You did think to `\usepackage{pgfplots}` ?

Comment: This was a part of the solution. Now it says `Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
i
\end{axis}
`

Comment: @MWijnand Please post some *complete* code allowing us to reproduce the new error. Your previous snippet is useless in this new scenario.

Comment: I don't get the `missing number` error, but I get a different error due to the empty line in the second to last `\addplot` (just before `};`) Also, you might want to set those figurelengths to some reasonable values.

Comment: I didn't try to compile the MWE but I noticed one thing that might be the culprit. In the preamble you declare two lenghts, `\figurewidth` and `\figureheight`, which are used in the included file but never defined. You could try to set them using `\setlength` command.

Comment: @LucaD Your comment solved my problem. Could you repeat it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, I'm posting my comment as an answer.

Some dimensions and coordinates in `example.tikz` are expressed in terms of the two lengths `\figurewidth` and `\figureheight`, but those are not defined within the file. In the preamble of the main `.tex` file `\figurewidth` and `\figureheight` are defined as lengths (with `\newlength`) but no values are assigned values (using for example `\setlength`).

Answer (score 1):

As `LucaD` answered, `\figurewidth`and `\figureheight` were not defined.